# Creating biblatex category based on Journal name

Tags: biblatex

I have used the following code to create cited/non-cited bibliographies.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
```

I want to further subdivide the 'Cited' bibliography called by

```
\printbibliography[category=cited, prenote={JoPE}]
```

into two sections. The first section is every cited reference except those for the journal named 'Foobar'. The next section is for cited references in the journal 'Foobar'. Both sections need to have prenotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use something like this:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldequalstr{journaltitle}{JoPE}
    {\addtocategory{citedjope}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}}
```

Of course, you may have more complicated conditions.

Another method is to use the `check` option of the `\printbibliography` command (see the manual n.3.6.9). For example:

```
\defbibcheck{JoPE}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{journaltitle}{JoPE}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{noJoPE}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{journaltitle}{JoPE}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
...
% for all cited except JoPE
\printbibliography[category=cited,check=noJoPE, prenote={noJoPE}]
% for all cited JoPE
\printbibliography[category=cited,check=JoPE, prenote={JoPE}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Can you tell me a reference for finding out more about conditional operators such as \iffieldequalstr ?

Comment: This is from the `biblatex` manual, section 4.6.2 'Stand-alone Tests'. The next section is also relevant, it's about complex tests.